# Enforce a rule that calling function should add constantness to value returned by the called function

Tags: c++, return-value, const-cast

I have the following function defined in a header file :

```
uint32_t get_id(void) const { return m_id; }
```

I want to enforce a rule that whichever function calls the above function should add constantness to the value returned , as in :

```
const uint32_t = const_cast(get_id);
```

Is that possible in C++ ?

Comment: Why? You are not returning a reference.

Comment: Do you maybe mean declaring the return value `const uint32_t`?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow That has no effect for built-in types like `uint32_t`, and is a bad idea in general. It still does not prevent the caller from copying it.

Comment: @Angew thanks for making that clear. I agree with Johnny Mopp then, who addresses the point in enforcing that rule.

Comment: This could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/201677). Can you explain your reasons?

Comment: if it were possible still you can copy from returned value later into a non-const variable

Comment: @Yola  - is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: I removed the "-Werror=ignored-qualifiers" flag from the makefile. And the first const in the function definition threw an error. So, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that for `uint32_t`.

What you could do would be to define a class that prohibited any modification (and containing the `uint32_t` as a private member) and return an object of that class.

This includes making `T operator=(const T&)` non-callable (private or `=delete`), see e.g. [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

You would still need a method for extracting the underlying `uint32_t` - but at least you would avoid accidental changes of the returned value - if that was the underlying issue you tried to solve.

Comment: Note that nothing would prevent copying that class, and that the returned `uint32_t` cannot be modified in-place anyway. So I can't see how this would help.

Comment: By prohibiting modifications of objects of the class, it could prevent "auto x=get_id(); x=get_id(); " and "auto x=get_id(); x++;" - similarly as if x were const. Why someone would want that I don't know.

Comment: @Angew .... So, if someone were to copy this class, they would be able to modify the returned value ?

Comment: @anju.gopinath Well, if the class prevents modification, then no. But either you must not offer a way of extracting the `uint32_t`, or anyone can get that value and then modify it to their heart's content. They could even do `uint32_t x = get_id().getValue();`. Which is why I claim this cannot be reasonably answered without knowing the underlying motivation.